# Using avg in spring on a project aggregation

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have the below query working as intended in mongo:

```
 db.test.aggregate([{$unwind: "$reports"}, {$project:  {reports: 1, avg: {$avg: "$reports.linesCount"}}}`])
```

However, I'm unable to convert this into Java via spring. You can't seem to run aggregation functions like avg on a ProjectionOperation, but it is possible on a GroupOperation. There isn't an avg() method at all a ProjectionOperation.

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation( 
                Aggregation.unwind("$reports"), 
                Aggregation.group(Fields.fields("_id"))
                .avg("reports.linesCount").as("avg"));
```

Any idea why this might be the case, when it clearly is possible in mongo? Is there some other way to translate my query into Java?

Answer (score 0):

Your query: `{reports: 1, avg: {$avg: "$reports.linesCount"}}`

aggregates on `reports.linesCount` field, but your java code is trying to aggregate on `.avg("reports.processingTime")`

So you might operate on wrong field. Check your query

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. It shouldn't matter as both fields are functionally identical in this context.